# Prove by contradiction: $2^n\not\in O(3^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just try
By contradiction : $\sim 2^n\in O(3^n)$

Therefore $\sim2^n \leq c\cdot 3^n$

$\frac{2^n}{3^n} \leq c$

$(\frac{2}{3})^n \leq c$

$\log\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \leq \log(c)$

$n \leq \log\left(\frac{c}{2/3}\right)$

Is it correct?

Comment: $\frac{\log(c)}{\log(2/3)} \neq \log \left(\frac{c}{2/3}\right)$

Comment: There are a couple of issues. First, $\log \frac{2}{3} < 0$, so the direction of the inequality should be reversed when you divide both sides by it. Second, $\frac{\log a}{\log b} \ne \log \frac{a}{b}$, as is implied by your last step.

Comment: But surely $2^n\in o(3^n)\subset O(3^n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other commenters has said, your last step is incorrect. For solving the problem, a simpler way is just to show that there exists a $c$ such that $2^n\le c3^n$. It should be clear that $c=1$ would be a good guess.

Now, showing $2^n\le 3^n$ is equivalent to showing $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \le 1$. You can prove this by induction or some analysis theorem.

**Edit**: Oh, I hadn't realized that your question is false. $2^n$ is indeed in $O(3^n)$, as shown here.